# How nanoScroller could be implemented with Ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, nanoscroller

We would like to implement [nanoScroller](https://github.com/jamesflorentino/nanoScrollerJS) to ckeditor.

Could any one can help us to achieve this ?

Comment: Implement how? To replace the scrollbars? The add scrolling content? What do you want to do? What have you tried?

Comment: If their is fix height of ckeditor & content height is greater than ckeditor fix height, than browser display normal scrollbar, i want to replace that scroll bar to nano scrollbar.